# the button works only once

Tags: ios, swift

I have a page which contains two text fields, 2 labels and a button. When the button is clicked I am just checking if the fields are not empty and validate them. This works fine. But I can click the button only once. After that nothing will change and I'm not able to press the button or edit the text fields!

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func loginbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    showActivityIndicator(uiView: view)

    emailerrormsg.isHidden=true
    passworderrormsg.isHidden=true

    if emailtf.text == "" && passwordtf.text == "" {
        emailerrormsg.text = "Email is required!"
        emailerrormsg.isHidden = false
        passworderrormsg.text = "Password is required!"
        passworderrormsg.isHidden = false
        stopActivityIndicator()
    }
    else if emailtf.text == ""{
        emailerrormsg.text = "Email is required!"
        emailerrormsg.isHidden = false
        stopActivityIndicator()

    }
    else if !(isValidEmail(testStr: emailtf.text!)){
        emailerrormsg.text = "Please enter a valid email!"
        emailerrormsg.isHidden = false
        stopActivityIndicator()
    }else if passwordtf.text == "" {
        passworderrormsg.text = "Password is required!"
        passworderrormsg.isHidden = false
        stopActivityIndicator()
    }

    else{
        hashedpass = (passwordtf.text!).sha1()
        self.login(email: emailtf.text!, password: hashedpass)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    func stopActivityIndicator(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingView.isHidden = true
    }
}
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
    let container: UIView = UIView()
    container.frame = uiView.frame
    container.center = uiView.center

    loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y:  0,width: 80,height: 80)
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.27, blue:0.60, alpha:1.0)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    let actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    actInd.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0.0,width: 40.0,height: 40.0);
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
        UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    actInd.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2,y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);
    loadingView.addSubview(actInd)
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    uiView.addSubview(container)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Does it only freeze when your email is valid or does it freeze like that in all cases?

Comment: @NaderBesada in all cases

Comment: What is happening in showActivityIndicator/stopActivityIndicator? perhaps you are making view unresponsive in show method but not reverting the change in stop

Comment: have you checked your UI inspector if there is any view above the button that's taking the event?

Comment: @PuneetSharma just posted them in my post .. please check them

Comment: @AatishMolasi how to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding loading view in the stop method. Instead, hide container view. For this, you would need to make container view a class level object(just as you have made loading view)

Comment: You are welcome. It is better to abstract the loader functionality into a object. That way, you can reuse it elsewhere in your app as well.

Comment: can you please give me an example how to do that? sorry im new to this